# Posting a csv file using python directly to php endpoint

Tags: php, python, csv

I am working on an application which gives users access by uploading them in a csv file, and having some issues.

The file is sent over multiple requests which I see in the network recorder, the form data of the first request looking like:

files[]: (binary)
passid: 4
teamid: 6
action: teaminitialcheck

The second request that gets sent looks like:

files[]: (binary)
passid: 4
teamid: 6
action: teaminitialcheck
sendemail: 1
action: teamcreateusers
uniqueid: 48vkcuurjowt

The final request looks like:

action: createusersstatus
passid: 4
uniqueid: 48vkcuurjowt
teamdetails: {"cohort_6":1}

The uniqueid is randomly generated - which I can send whatever I want along with (I believe), the passid is always 4 and teamid i can scrape from the page so that isn't an issue.

What is an issue is that using the following code:

```
login_headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36 '
    }


login_data = {
        'username': 'xxxx@xxxx',
        'password': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'anchor': ''
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = login_headers
    s.upload_headers = upload_headers
    s.data = login_data
    url = BaseTest.getSiteURL()
    r = s.post(url + '/login/index.php', data=login_data)
    print(r.status_code)
    csv_file = CSV.get_csv()
    file = {'file': open(csv_file, 'rb')}
    step1_data = {
            'action': 'teaminitialcheck',
            'passid': '4',  # Should always be 4 - seems to be the id of the button
            'teamid': '6'  # Has to be scraped from DOM
        }
        r1 = s.post(url + '/local/admin/pages/user/ajax/getcsv.php', params=step1_data, files=file)
        print(r1.status_code)
        step2_data = {
            'passid': '4',
            'teamid': '6',
            'action': 'teaminitialcheck',
            'sendemail': '1',
            'action': 'teamcreateusers',
            'uniqueid': '4cxfre2236u8'
        }
        r2 = s.post(url + '/local/admin/pages/user/ajax/getcsv.php', data=step2_data, files=file)
        #  time.sleep(15)
        print(r2.status_code)
        step3_data = {
            'action': 'createusersstatus',
            'passid': '4',  # Should always be 4 - seems to be the id of the button
            'uniqueid': '4cxfre2236u8',
            'teamdetails': '{"cohort_6":1}'
        }
        r3 = s.post(url + '/local/admin/pages/user/ajax/getcsv.php', data=step3_data)
        print(r3.status_code)
```

I get a 200 response - but I don't see the users get uploaded, and the response content says as much:

```
b'{"meta":{"fields":false,"usercount":0,"errors":[""],"invalidemail":0,"needseats":false,"displaydownload":false,"general":{"users":[],"errors":[],"invalidemails":0}},"action":"teaminitialcheck"}'
```

So it's as if my code is fine - but the contents of the file aren't getting sent along. The file itself is simply 2 lines, one with email, first name, last name and corresponding values on the second line.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I answered my own question.

That answer being:

The site - when it takes a CSV file to upload users to, will simply pop each line off and feed the data one at a time. I found a previously unnoticed option to upload a single user which takes some simple data that I am assuming is each line of data from the CSV is thrown at - and that data I can generate or scrape from elsewhere that will suffice as a solution for now.

If they still need to test the uploading of CSV functionality - they can do this at a lower layer than what I am working at and I shouldn't have to worry myself at the UI layer - I think...